# Shell command for the normal program termination of Skype from the command line

Tags: shell, unix

Would the following be the right way to do it in your opinion? Can you suggest a better alternative or, if not, is there something that can be done to make the existing version better?

```
ps -e | grep skype | cut -d" " -f1 | xargs kill -s term
```

Comment: I would install Linux-style `killall` to take care of this.

Comment: @chicks In Linux, `/usr/bin/pkill` is in the same procps package as `/bin/ps`, but `/usr/bin/killall` is in a separate psmisc package. Also, fun fact: on Solaris, [`killall`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killall) actually tries to kill _everything_ that it possibly can, regardless of command-line parameters! For both reasons, I recommend `pkill` over `killall`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments have pointed out, there exist tools to match processes by name. This is roughly equivalent (better than) what you're trying to do:

```
pkill skype
```

It's better because:

1. It's shorter and cleaner
2. It won't kill itself

By the second point I mean that `ps -e | grep skype` will match the `grep` process itself too. That won't happen when using `pkill`.

#### Code review

If we wanted to imitate `pkill`, I would suggest writing like this:

```
ps -e | awk '/[s]kype/ { print $1 }' | xargs kill
```

That is:

- Replace two processes with one (`grep` + `cut` with `awk`)
- Use `[s]kype` instead of `skype` is a common trick to make the `awk` itself not match
- Drop `-s term` from `kill`, as `TERM` is the default signal anyway